# Custom option for delivery date not display in Magento checkout page as desired

Tags: php, magento, datetime

I add `custom option` for product to select the `delivery date` in **Magento 1.9.0.1**. It's `input type is Date`.( If I use type as `Date & Time`, dropdown box will come to select time. I need to select time from picker) I set

```
 var calendarSetupObject = {
                inputField  : "' . $this->getId() . '",
                ifFormat: "%Y-%m-%e %H:%M:%S", //changed line
                showsTime: true,               //changed line
                button      : "' . $this->getId() . '_trig",
                align       : "Bl",
                singleClick : true,
```

in **app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Html/Date.php**
Now I can select both `date and time`. Look the picture below
[image]

But in `checkout page` The `Delivery date shows only date not time`. Please refer below image
[image]

Also in `backend sales->order details page` shows `only date`, I `need both date and time.`

Please Help me..

Answer (score 0):

First of all apology for delayed reply. I followed the below approach to get rid of this problem.

1 .First of override the core files
local\Mage\Core\Block\Html\Date.php with following changes.(As you mentioned).

2.Added following js script to modify the hour and time field.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
   var dateField = jQuery('#product-options-wrapper').find('.input-text');
   jQuery(dateField).on('change',function(){
        var _self = jQuery(this).attr('id');
        var dateTime = jQuery(this).val();
        var temp=  _self.split('date');
        dateTime = dateTime.split(' ');
        var cTime =dateTime[1];
        var selected_time = cTime.split(':');
        jQuery('#'+temp[0]+'hour').val(parseInt(selected_time[0]));
        jQuery('#'+temp[0]+'minute').val(parseInt(selected_time[1]));
    });
});
```

Please make sure type should be date time of custom option.if you want to hide hour and minute field, please set visibility hidden of span with class time-picker on date.phtml page.

```
<span class="time-picker" style="visibility: hidden">
```